# Entry into the US without stamped H4 visa

Tags: visas, usa

My I-797 which I received in the US is valid till 2017 but I have not had my H-4 visa stamped as yet. I am currently in India.

Will I be able to fly to the US with the I-797 alone, or will I be stopped from flying because I do not have the H-4 visa stamped?

Comment: What country are we taking about here? Not everyone might be familiar with specific terminology as 797 and h4.

Comment: You better post this question in http://forum.murthy.com/. This is not the best place to post immigration related questions. And you can't enter to US with out valid visa (i.e visa stamp). Your I-797 is kind of EAD when you are inside US only. You can't enter to US alone with I-797 approved petetion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need a **visa** (visa stamp) to apply for admission to the U.S. You will not be allowed to board the flight without a visa, and if you managed to get to the U.S., you will be denied entry and potentially get a ban because you tried to enter without a visa.